# iterate a dictionary inorder of elements

Tags: python

given

```
post = {"comments": [
    {
        "_id": 2, 
        "detail": "info1",
        "responses": [
            {
                "_id": 3,
                "responses": [],
                "detail": "info2"
            }]
    },
    {
        "_id": 0, 
        "responses": [],
        "detail": "info3",
    }]
}
```

visually this is just

```
[comment comment]
    [child comment]
[parent comment]
```

I am trying to traverse through each comment from first to last

so info1 then info2 then info3

My attempt

```
queue = []
comment1 = post['comments']
queue.append(comment1)
for responses in queue:
    for comment in responses:
        print(comment['detail'])
        if(comment['responses'] != []):
            queue.append(comment['responses'])
```

this prints

```
info1
info3
info2
```

Anyway to get what I want by tweaking this a bit?

Comment: Beside the point, but `queue = []; comment1 = post['comments']; queue.append(comment1)` is a roundabout way of writing `queue = [post['comments']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code did what it did is because it added the replies *at the end* of the queue, instead of directly after it. To fix this you'll need to make a function:

```
def process_comment(comment):
    print(comment['detail'])
    if(comment['responses'] !=  []):
        for i in comment['responses']:
            process_comment(i)

queue = []
comment1 = post['comments']
queue.append(comment1)
for responses in queue:
    for comment in  responses:
        process_comment(comment)
```

The above code should work.

Comment: `if(comment['responses'] !=  []):` is redundant because you're iterating over `comment['responses']` next, and if it's empty, the loop won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to walk the comment tree. Here's one way:

```
def replies_deep(comment):
    print(comment['detail'])
    for response in comment['responses']:  # Iterate over responses
        replies_deep(response)  # Recurse into the response's responses

for top in post['comments']:
    replies_deep(top)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; it uses a recursive function to get comments:

```
#Bad code, but simplest in this circumstance.
def iterate(arr):
  global queue
  for comment in arr:
    queue.append(comment["detail"])
    print(comment["detail"]) #For your debug.
    iterate(comment["responses"])

post = {} #Put your data here
queue = []
iterate(post["comments"])
```

The function calls itself over and over, reading replies to replies until it finishes. It produces your desired result, prioritising going down trees before across.